# CMAKE/MAKEFILE : /usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld : Cannot find -lfftw3f

Tags: c, ubuntu, gcc, makefile, cmake

I am running some c code using cmake and makefile on the server, and i am using a library, but when i run the make, i got this error :

`/usr/bin/x86_64-linux-gnu-ld: cannot find -lfftw3f`

The library is already installed and located in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/, any suggestions ? here is my CMAKE file

```
cmake_minimum_required(VERSION 3.5)
project(sfa C)

set(CMAKE_C_STANDARD 11)

set(LIBSFA src/pqueue.c src/sfa_file_loaders.c  src/sfa_trie.c src/sfa_node.c   src/ts.c src/calc_utils.c src/sfa_query_engine.c  src/sfa_file_buffer.c src/sfa_file_buffer_manager.c src/dft.c)
add_library(libsfa STATIC "${LIBSFA}")

add_executable(sfa src/sfa.c )
link_directories(/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/)
target_link_libraries(sfa libsfa m fftw3f jemalloc readline)
```

Thank you

Comment: Did you run `ldconfig` after installing the library? The `cmake` is all well and good, but it might help if you can post the relevant portion of the [generated] `Makefile`. And, the output of the `make` command itself (i.e. `make` will show the _exact_ command that it used). You said the library is in `/home/usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/` Is that _literally_ true or is the `/home` prefix a typo?

Comment: What OS [and distro] are you using? The normal place for `libfftw*` is `/usr/lib64` (under (e.g.) linux fedora). I notice your install place (and the `x86_64-linux-gnu-*` prefix on your `ld` command) looks more like a cross-build installation than native. Can you use the `file` [and/or `readelf`] command on your libraries to verify that it's built for the correct arch?

Comment: @CraigEstey i am running the code on a ubuntu server, and sorry the library is in /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/ actually, i think the architecture is not the problem since the installation has been successfully done...

Comment: Well, then. It should be working, but it's not. What about the things I suggested? Running `ldconfig`. post `Makefile`. post `make` output. running `file` on the files? Try, running `ld` with `-t`. Is there an `ld.so.conf` entry for `/usr/lib/x86_64-linux`? Also, you can run `ld` under `strace`.

Comment: I dont have sudo rights so ldconfig doesnt works :\

Comment: You can do the other things I mentioned. They don't need `sudo`. Try `ldconfig -p` [it works for an ordinary user]. What's the [your] issue with posting the `Makefile` and `make` output and the other actions? Depending on those, you could edit the `cmake` file and/or `Makefile` to force the correct search path.

Answer (score 1):

Normally, there's a difference between a library that is there to supply programs that have previously been developed to use it, to the files you actually need to include some library to be used.

CMake checks if the **development** version of the library is installed, by querying the `#include <blahblah.h>` files that belong to it.  If it doesn't find them, then it complaints.

The problem most probably will be this:  You have installed the library on the system, but not the development version, with all the include files needed to use it for development.  Probably you'll need to install some `libfftw3-dev` package or similar name to install the include files, and so, be able to use the library for development.

Answer (score 0):

Programs you compile from source and make install will more often end up in /usr/local/bin, /usr/local/lib, etc, and you may have problems with that since the user-installed path in Debian/Ubuntu is /usr and not /usr/local.
So instead of compiling the program with default mode, do :

```
cd $HOME && mkdir local local/src local/bin local/lib && cd local/src
wget link_the_file.tar.gz && tar -zxvf the_file.tar.gz
cd the_file_decompressed && ./configure --prefix=$HOME/local --enable-type-prefix
make && make install
```

make sure that $HOME/Path is in your path.